# How to declare complex numbers without their fields getting mixed up?

Tags: c++

I try to create complex numbers but for whatever reason they always come up real part having imaginary value and imaginary part getting zeroed.
For example I expected this little test app to print several instances of (1,2) but all I'm getting is (2,0) no matter how I try to aproach it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::complex<double>** complexdouble_c;
    complexdouble_c = new std::complex<double>*[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        complexdouble_c[i] = new std::complex<double>[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && i < 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 && j < 15; j++) {
                double real = 1;
                double imag = 2;
                complexdouble_c[i][j] = (real, imag);
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && i < 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 && j < 15; j++) {
            std::cout << complexdouble_c[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::complex<double> complexdouble;
    double real = 1.0;
    double imag = 2.0;
    complexdouble = (real, imag);
    std::cout << complexdouble;
    std::cout << complexdouble.real();
    std::cout << complexdouble.imag();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You should probably reconsider your tendency to write Java code in C++. There's nothing about this program that requires the use of `new`. All that accomplishes is creating a bunch of memory leaks, and plenty of opportunities for misuse or improper use of pointers resulting in undefined behavior and crashes.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik if I were to try and make a 2d array I would reserve memory for it. Is there anything about std::complex that makes it different? (Also I don't really know Java. I just simply try to make a dummy example that I'll try to turn into dynamic array.)

Comment: Less opportunities for bugs, and no memory leaks to deal with. And this approach actually wastes more memory than a single 2-dimensional array, or `std::array`.

Comment: `complexdouble = (real, imag);` does not do what you think it does. `(real, imag)` means "evaluate real and throw it away, then evaluate imag and return its value". See the duplicate for a more detailed explanation, as well as a list of correct ways to assign complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare in this format. This will give the following output

```
std::complex<double> c(1, 2);
// 1 + 2i
```